# DB objects relations visualization

Tags: database, object, visualization, data-visualization, relation

I'm not guru in DBA, so I'll try explain what I want in terms I imagine it.

I have Oracle DB with network devices. each device has ports which has parent device/port

I want some tool which will automaticaly create visual map of this device relations.
Will create "Network Map" based on this relations.

It's would be better if this tool will have some output ready for web publishing, or web based tool from the begging. Also if it will automatically update "picture" as soon as I add new relation/object

From far it looks something like Gource http://youtu.be/E5xPMW5fg48
But not exactly what i need

Hope to get some suggestion.
Thanks in advance!

UPD: found another tool: [Gephi](https://gephi.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).  It was created specifically for visualising large graphs of network nodes.

It's not out of the box; you'll have to write some code that:

1. Reads data on the devices & their relationships
2. Creates the graphviz input file
3. generates the diagram by calling the graphviz binary.

There are many ways to do that.  One of the easiest is to use python with the [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) library.

Note that graphviz generates static images (jpeg / tiff etc.) so you'd have to regenerate on demand.

There are more interactive toolkits available, e.g. [protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) / [infovis](http://thejit.org/).  Both are javascript based and render directly in the browser.

hth.

Comment: thank you. i'll check out all this solutions as well as [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/)... i was hopping to see some ready-to-go solution, without writing code

Comment: no worries.  Prefuse may be an option, although not sure it's still actively developed.  iirc one of the javascript toolkits (protovis/infovis) is the successor to prefuse.  Good luck anyway.